# How to generate Json from another master Json config file

Tags: java, json

I have a master JSON file that contains the config text as a template. Something like below.

```
{
    "first": "This is the first line",
    "second": "This is the second line",
    "third": "This is the third line",
    "fourth": "This is the fourth line"
}
```

I want to generate another JSON file from the master above, based on some rules. For example, see the snippet below for my requirements

```
{
    "first": "This is the first custom line",
    "second": [I want this populated from master.second and master.fourth],
    "third": [I want this populated from master.third],
    "fifth": "This is the local fifth section"
}
```

Looking for recommendations about the best way of doing this. In general I want to be able to configure large number of complex files.

My application is Java based, so any recommendation that uses JSON, Java or any other compatible tools would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: This is too broad. You can start by looking into various existing template engines, of which there are plenty that support JSON formats, I'm sure, or you can write one yourself. Ultimately though, this question is too non-specific to have a useful answer in context of StackOverflow.

Comment: Following along from @M. Prohorov's comment. The best answer is to find a JSON library of your choice, load the config files, and programmatically generate the "master" JSON. Then if you have specific issues or problems in that implementation come back and ask about that.

Answer (score 1):

altho those json looks similar, they can't mapped to the same Java object, the `seconds` and `third` fields are of different type

so based on your assume knolegde I think the simplest soultion will be to create 2 classes, like

```
class MasterJsonObject {
    private String first;
    private String second;
    private String third;
    private String fourth;
}

class GeneratedJsonObject {
    private String first;
    private List<String> second;
    private List<String> third;
    private String fourth;
}
```

read the json and map it to `MasterJsonObject`, create `GeneratedJsonObject` like

```
GeneratedJsonObject generatedJsonObject = new GeneratedJsonObject();
generatedJsonObject.setFirst(masterJsonObject.getFirst());
generatedJsonObject.setSecond(Arrays.asList(masterJsonObject.getSecond(), masterJsonObject.getForth()));
...
```

and you can write the `generatedJsonObject` as json afterwards

you can use generic and other methods to achieve a more robust behaviour...

to read and write json with Java, I suggest looking into [Jackson](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson)

I assume in your code `"second": [I want this populated from master.second and master.fourth],` meaning a `list`, if you just want to concat strings, like

`"second": "This is the second line This is the fourth line"`

the answer changed by:

- don't need a second class (`generatedJsonObject`)
- create the jsonObject with `.setSecond(masterJsonObject.getSecond() + " " + masterJsonObject.getForth());`